# Java syntax >>, &, ? and :

Tags: java, syntax

I don't understand what the >>, &, ? and : mean in this program:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
        final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
```

Could you help me ? Google doesn't do search on non-alphanumeric characters...

Comment: The Java Tutorial is your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html.

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [Bitwise Shift](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) - `>>`
- [Bitwise AND](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)  - `&`
- [Ternary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) - `?` `:`

Answer (score 5):

Let's take these one at a time...

```
final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
            >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
```

These are bitwise operators.  The `&` is ANDing the bits in `action` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK` together.

The `>>` is shifting that result.

Binyamin referenced a good page on [bitwise operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for you.

```
final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

This is a ternary operator.  Essentially it's saying "if pointerIndex is equal to 0, return 1, else return 0.  The way you express this is (boolean decision) ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse

Answer (score 4):

`>>` is the shift operator and it shifts a bit pattern to the right

(You can google shift operator)

`&` is a bitwise and operator (search bitwise operators)

`? :` is short form for if - then -else
`[if cond] ? [then] : [else]`

Refer
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Please don't describe `?:` as a "short form of if-else", because it's not.  It's not designed for control flow.

Comment: It is actually described like this in the documentation though.. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Answer (score 1):

- Here `>>` is `shift` operator.
- `?` `:` is `Ternary` Operator
- `&` is `Bitwise and` operator

Take a look here for [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)